# NTP Shared Memory Driver Structure

Tags: shared-memory, ntp

I would like to use the shared memory driver to push time from a GPS
receiver into NTP (Note 1) - host OS is Linux, using NTP 4.2.6p5.
According to [documentation](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/drivers/driver28.html), I
need to populate the following structure in shared memory:

```
struct shmTime {
  int    mode; /* 0 - if valid set
            *       use values,
            *       clear valid
            * 1 - if valid set
            *       if count before and after read of
            *       values is equal,
            *         use values
            *       clear valid
            */
  int    count;                  /* See documentation for "mode" on the site */
  time_t clockTimeStampSec;      /* external clock */
  int    clockTimeStampUSec;     /* external clock */
  time_t receiveTimeStampSec;    /* internal clock, when external value was received */
  int    receiveTimeStampUSec;   /* internal clock, when external value was received */
  int    leap;                   /* ??? */
  int    precision;              /* Precision of the timestamp, in 2^precision seconds */
  int    nsamples;               /* Set by NTPD - do not populate */
  int    valid;                  /* Shared memory is valid */
  int    dummy[10];
};
```

The major fields missing are a precise definition of "Timestamp" and "leap". I take it that timestamp is Unix time, in UTC, but how is it to be adjusted for leap seconds, and how does this interact with the "leap" field? Canonical examples of using the interface such as [shmpps.c](http://time.qnan.org/#driver-shm) don't really answer the question.

(Note 1: In this project, we are processing our own GPS solution and time based on raw observables and are hence are not using NMEA or other GPS protocol. PPS is supplied to us via a GPIO line and we are using the ATOM driver to capture this via linuxpps)